# Json.Net cannot deserialize objects with multiple generic types?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a property of the type `Dictionary<string, int>` when sending data from a server to a client.

**So if i serialize this simplified object:**

```
class Foo
{
  public Dictionary<string, int> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**I get this nice json (using TypeNameHandling.All):**

```
{
  "$type": "Foo",
  "Bar": {
    "$type": "Dictionary<String, Int32>"
  }
}
```

The problem is on the deserializing side where I use a custom Binder overriding the *BindToType* to deserialize. But when doing so, the *typeName* is not correct and i get a `"Dictionary<String"` instead.

```
public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
  if (typeName == "Dictionary<String, Int32>")
  {
    // I never get here because typeName is "Dictionary<String"
    return typeof(Dictionary<string, int>);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: why don't you use JsonConverers while deserializing/

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh you are welcome to post an example as an answer if you like. But remember; most of the time I don't know what type of object to expect on the deserialization side.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: When I serialize your type `Foo` with `TypeNameHandling.All`, I get `"$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",` which is not what you show.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pfD2CW).  Please provide a [mcve] showing how you generated that `"$type"` property initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this for deserialization -

```
class customBinder : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var type = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        var data = JObject.Load(reader);

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString(), type.GetType(), new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });

        return obj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

    }
}
```